# Convert UTC date/time values to local time values in SQL Server and DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to convert the date/time values stored in UTC-0 (GMT) to a user preferred time zone value by passing in the time zone (e.g EST, CST etc). However, SQL Server doesn't seem to have a method that takes in a time zone, but does honor the offset. I was wondering if any one had any luck doing so, so that the date/time value reflects the DST change, when a SQL query is issues against the table that contains these values. Oracle is the only database, that seems to honor the Time Zone as well as offset. Please advice.

Comment: AFAIK the here described way http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31146/SQL-2005-Time-Zone-Conversion-Functions is the only one without using self written extendend procedures. If needed I could this kind of extended procedure, conversion is ready, I only would have to encapsulate in appropriate DLL.